# checkbox default to checked unless unchecked by user

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

How do I change the php below so that the initial view is checked, but if the user unchecks is and submits the form, it then stays unchecked each time they access the form (until they elect to make the value checked again)?

```
class My_Recent_Posts_Widget extends WP_Widget {

 function form( $instance ) {

     /* form code here...*/

    <input 
     type="checkbox" 
     class="checkbox" 
     id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id("excerpt"); ?>" 
     name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name("excerpt"); ?>"<?php checked( (bool) $instance["excerpt"], true ); ?> 
    />

    /* form code here...*/

   }
}
```

**UPDATE**: placing checked="checked" inside the input field is not what I'm looking for. The reason is that every time the user clicks to uncheck it, after the submit it always comes back checked. Once the user unchecks the option, it should remain unchecked for them on subsequent visits to the form. However, using checked=checked insures that the default state is ALWAYS checked, regardless if the user has previously unchecked this particular item.

I just need the *default* value to be checked, but if the user has unchecked it even once, I need it to stick so that its unchecked every time they open the form, until they choose to check it themselves. I believe the answer lies in the status of the $instance["excerpt"] item in the database.

Comment: you'd have to maintain an indepedent list of which boxes need to be checked, and then reapply that list each time?

Comment: There is not enough code to answer. In what context is your code happening?

Comment: @brasofilo - the context is inside a widget form control in WordPress. I've updated the post with the wrapper function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this article by Justin Tadlock: [The complete guide to creating widgets in WordPress 2.8](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/26/the-complete-guide-to-creating-widgets-in-wordpress-28).

There, you'll see that when parsing the arguments of the form you can have `$defaults`:

```
function form( $instance ) {

    /* Set up some default widget settings. */
    $defaults = array( 
            'title'    => 'Example'
        ,   'name'     => 'John Doe'
        ,   'sex'      => 'male'
        ,   'show_sex' => true 
    );
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put : `checked="checked"`

Inside your input tag.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we are talking about [WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) here, you are using:

```
<?php checked( (bool) $instance["excerpt"], true ); ?>
```

So the checkbox will be checked depending on the value of `$instance["excerpt"]`.

You should modify the condition to your needs but that is hard to do for us without seeing more details.

**Edit:** If the value is stored in `$instance["excerpt"]` you should make sure that the default value in the database for a new user is the checked value (`1` for example). That way, as long as the user does not change it, it remains checked.

Comment: Yes, WordPress. So is there a way to do this? I want to default the value to checked. However, once the user has unchecked it, I want to somehow change the value in the database to unchecked, so that each time the user loads the widget again, they don't have to keep clicking to uncheck the option. PS: This is a widget control panel.

Comment: @RegEdit What variable is the widgets checkbox stored in / how are you storing it in the database / what are the possible values of your variable?

Comment: +1 Thanks for playing this out with me and I get where you are coming from. But, the problem is that when user unchecks the checkbox, @instance['excerpt'] carries no value back to the db. So there is nothing to test against.

Comment: @RegEdit If you want the setting to persist, you need to store it somewhere. How are you doing that now? You could use a session or a cookie if you don't want to use the database. A cookie can have a longer life-time. Problem with both is that you don't have access to them (for example for counting purposes). I would go for a server-side (db...) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the checked attribute

```
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  class="checkbox" 
  checked="checked" 
  id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id("excerpt"); ?>"
  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name("excerpt"); ?>"<?php checked( (bool) $instance["excerpt"], true ); ?>
/>
```